# How do I do scroll animation like Google Maps in Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, sass

I'm doing an Ionic app 2 and I'm trying to reproduce the same behavior as the google maps list. I would like to be able to scroll up and down but I can not.

[animation Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV3We.gif)

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/README.md

Comment: This plugin already I'm using it. I would like to recreate the animation as in the photo I posted

Comment: The maps plugin recognizes the z-index of html elements. So you can cover with another div over the map. But you need to create the slide up div by your self.

Comment: I already have a list above the map. The problem is that if my list has for example two elements and fixed a height covering the remaining space, the list does not scroll up and down.